# How can I add an event to multiple elements at once, by id, in mootools?

Tags: mootools

I have two element IDs, a and b.  I want to do something like this:

```
[$('a'), $('b')].addEvent('click', myFunction);
```

but that particular code gives "TypeError: (intermediate value).addEvent is not a function".

Do I need to explicitly loop (or duplicate the addEvent call)?

```
[$('a'), $('b')].each(function(el){
    el.addEvent('click', myFunction);
});
```

or

```
$('a').addEvent('click', myFunction);
$('b').addEvent('click', myFunction);
```

Or is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the elements constructor or let `$$` (`document.getElements`) do it for you.

examples:

```
// via slick - same as document.getElements 
$$("#a, #b").addEvent('click', fn);

// with existing elements:
$$([el1, el2]).addEvent('click', fn);

// with Elements constructor w/o involving slick if you have them saved
new Elements([el1, el2]).addEvent('click', fn);
```